# 1) "before all" hook: prepare suite for " "

Tags: solidity, testing, truffle-test, out-of-gas

I am trying to create an Integrated test (to test multiple smartContracts working together). I re-initialize them inside **beforeEach()** function. So I get the clean test for each test case. I have done the same things in other integrated tests,(using the same contracts), but here I get this errors.

[image: Error screenshot]

As you can see, there was no issues in **IntegrationTestWhitelist** (all 4 sub-tests passed)

However, **TransactionTests** failed

[image: Error2]

While troubleshooting I figured out that, the **TransactionTests** works only if I initialize two or less smartContracts in **beforeEach()**.

Any more than that and I get "out of gas" error. I tried to initialize/comment them in different combinations too, and it is always fine as long as I do not initialize more than two. There seems to be nothing wrong with contracts individually. Rather it looks like the are "too" expensive when combined.

So I wonder if anyone had a similar issue?

The Code:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;


import "../../../contracts/Whitelist.sol";
import "../../../contracts/Blacklist.sol";
import "../../../contracts/dgE.sol";
import "../../../contracts/ECB.sol";
import "truffle/Assert.sol";
import "truffle/DeployedAddresses.sol";

contract TransactionTests {

    //Contracts
    dgE public DGE;
    ECB public ecb;
    Whitelist public WHITELIST;
    Blacklist public BLACKLIST;


    // Run before every test function (Only works if I comment out any two of them)
    function beforeEach() public {
        DGE = new dgE();
        ecb= new ECB();
        WHITELIST = new Whitelist();
        BLACKLIST = new Blacklist();
    }

    /**
    * The function should always return the same value. (Just an initial test)
    */
    function testSender() public {
        Assert.equal(msg.sender,msg.sender,"Values should be Equal");
    }
```

Comment: Did you solve your problem bro?

Comment: You have the same issue??

Comment: Yes :((((((((((

Comment: I guess maybe its depends of contract count, im also try to use 2 contracts but got same errors

Comment: I did some tests, and it 100% isn't the contract count (I used 3-4 no problem). It seems to be related to contract size, or maybe some conflict in contract inheritance. (As some of my Contracts import a bunch of other contracts) 

Would love to contact you over Zoom/Discord or something to see your issue to compare our issues and get at the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error because of the solidity contract size issue, if your compiler is throwing an error about exceeding the maximum ~24kb size, fix the contract size issue first and the error will go away. This is what solved my similar problem.